# Install ssconvert (part of gnumeric) on a server without GNOME

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, csv, conversion

I need to use gnumeric's file conversion tool ssconvert on a server.

The problem is that gnumeric is a gnome application and can't be installed without a desktop installed.

There is also no separate packages for ssconvert, and I can not compile it from source code...

I need this specific conversion tool cause it can covert from Excel XML format to CSV, which I was unable to do with other excel conversion tools.

I am working on a ubuntu 12.04 server. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think many of the dependencies for gnumeric are actually "recommended" packages, not real dependencies. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnumeric
```

For me, this installed about 37MB of packages, most of which were libraries and icon themes, which I felt was tolerable.

Comment: I need access inside a chroot. `ssconvert` does not play nice without it's real deps.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're asking specifically about ssconvert, but in my case I gave up trying to install gnumeric without the Gnome dependencies. Instead, I'm using xls2csv (which is part of the catdoc package) with the same results.

Suppose you have a source.xls file. This command:

`xls2csv -s 8859-1 -d 8859-1 source.xls > destination.csv`

will do the trick. The parameters -s y -d specify the source and destination charset. This example will process a source file that includes special characters such as 'ñ'. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I have tried this one, but will not work with the XML format of excel. I still haven't found a tool that can convert from Excel XML format to CSV

Answer (score 1):

I just installed gnumerics on my Ubuntu server : it installs a lot of dependancies, such as gnome and others, which seems heavy, but you don't need to load the desktop environment to use ssconvert.

My advice is : simply install it, don't care about gnome and desktops.

Comment: I don't really know if it is a good idea to install gnome on servers... it kinda makes them slower I guess?

Comment: I'm reluctant to do this because I feel that anything you install introduces a potential security hole. I'd like to keep my servers as lean as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use in2csv of package csvkit.
https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/

Comment: not sure python is a fair trade.

Comment: This tool can't convert Excel XML (SpreadsheetML XLS)

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer from @IanPhillips:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnumeric
```

I've just tried this on a clean headless Ubuntu 20.04 server VM. `apt` claimed it would be a 115MB install; in the event, `df` showed a usage increase of 151,492 1K blocks. The packages installed don't seem objectionable, but it is pretty heavy. However, the current `in2csv` (1.0.6) is pretty useless, so had to be replaced. Note that a straightforward/naive `in2csv` install can use up 400MB just to get the *installer* (`apt install python3-pip`).

When installed this way, `ssconvert` correctly processes my xls and xlsx test files, with over 3000 test conversions on time-formatted cells. LibreOffice also converts these files correctly when run headless, but `in2csv` fails on the xls files.

---

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gnumeric-common gsfonts gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcolord2 libcups2
  libdatrie1 libepoxy0 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common libgraphite2-3 libgsf-1-114
  libgsf-1-common libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libharfbuzz0b libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpixman-1-0 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwebp6 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 pxlib1 ubuntu-mono
Suggested packages:
  gnumeric-plugins-extra fonts-liberation | ttf-mscorefonts-installer libgsf-1-dev colord cups-common gvfs liblcms2-utils librsvg2-bin
Recommended packages:
  gnumeric-doc evince lp-solve at-spi2-core libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgtk-3-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gnumeric gnumeric-common gsfonts gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcolord2 libcups2
  libdatrie1 libepoxy0 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common libgraphite2-3 libgsf-1-114
  libgsf-1-common libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libharfbuzz0b libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpixman-1-0 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwebp6 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 pxlib1 ubuntu-mono
0 upgraded, 66 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```